# 1000Z in the power circuit, is it a Ferrite Bead？

Tags: power-supply, ferrite-bead

[image]
is 1000Z a ferrite bead, and does it mean 1000Ω at 100MHz? OR something else? please help?

Comment: You should cite the document where you found the picture.

Comment: Once you get the part number from the BOM that accompanied the picture, you can read all about it from the manufacturer's datasheet.

Comment: It's from ADI CN0382, and yes as @BrianDrummond Said, it has bom, I just neglected it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely isolation of the Analog VDD and the Digital VDD to prevent digital switching noise in the load from showing up on your analog measurements and has nothing to do with the linear regulator function. Typically a ferrite bead between 470 and 1k Ohms at 100 MHz.

Comment: thank you very much, so 1000Z = 1Kohms at 100MHz, and Z = ohm at 100MHz?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable assumption based on the typical values I see used for analog VDD isolation.